# Returning deleted row in a trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement, postgraphile

I'm struggling to return anything inside an if statement which has delete before returning. I want to return the old row which was essentially deleted. Any help?

It returns the new row without problem since it's only updated, but I can't return the old row at all, it only returns null.

```
pgm.createTrigger(
    { schema: 'app_public', name: 'events_tasks' },
    'check_event_task_null',
    {
        when: 'AFTER',
        level: 'ROW',
        operation: 'UPDATE',
        language: 'plpgsql',
        replace: true
    },
    `BEGIN
        IF NEW."eventId" IS NULL THEN
                DELETE FROM app_public.events_tasks WHERE id = NEW.id;
                RETURN OLD;
        ELSE
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
    END`);
```